# MVC Rest and returning views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, restful-architecture

I'm trying to implement the restful convention on my controllers but am not sure how to  handle failing model validation in sending it back to the 'New' view from the Create action.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult New()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             // Want to return view "new" but with existing model
        }

        // Process my model
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("New", model);
    }

    // Process my model
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Granted I'm not familiar with the REST conventions, so I may be way off here ... (and I couldn't find a source that said that the New() method has to be parameterless in a few minutes googling)

You could change your New() method to

```
public ActionResult New(MyModel model = null)
{
    return View("New", model);
}
```

And then in your Create()

```
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return New(model)
         // Want to return view "new" but with existing model
    }
```

And check in your New view if a Model is set or not. The New() will still work perfectly without a parameter as it used to.

Comment: -1, this invokes the `New` action, not to mention that it will not work as you are in the context of the `Create` action which will look for a `Create.cshtml` view.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what he wants?

Comment: no that is not what he wants. He wants to render the `New` view from within the `Create` action, not to invoke the `New` action. There is a difference. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723531/mvc-rest-and-returning-views/6723775#6723775).

Comment: I know that. I just don't particularly like returning different views from different actions. There might be logic in the action that the view requires that could otherwise be missed. I prefer handling a situation like this by invoking New but with a model, and then in the logic check if the model is null or not.

Comment: that's a wrong pattern. Normally in the GET action you have code that fetches the model from the DB whereas in the POST action this model comes from the default model binder as user input. If you invoke the GET action by returning it you will loose what the user entered in the form. And as I said you code won't work because it will not find the `Create.cshtml` view. In the New action you will have to `return View("New", model);`.

Comment: Better now? :) I didn't realise that Create would still be looking for Create.cshtml if I return a different action. I never ran into this problem yet.

Comment: no, not better and I already explained why. At least this time your code will work but it is a bad pattern.