# MVC Restful routing and returning Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

My question is very similar to this one [MVC Rest and returning views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723531/mvc-rest-and-returning-views) but the answer isn't working for me. I have implemented Restful Routing in my MVC application using (http://restfulrouting.com/).

When I want to add a new record the url is:

```
localhost/operations/1/exhibits/new
```

This calls the New action which returns New.cshtml as the view which contains a form. When the user submits the form and the Create action is called successfully on the Exhibits controller.

If the model state has errors I would like to return back to the New view with the date entered by the use still in place and show an error message (not implemented yet).

At present

```
return View("New", model)
```

sends back the data and renders the "New" view but the url changes to:

```
/localhost/operations/1/exhibits
```

I have checked the route values and the action being returned still is "create". I have navigation links that are driven by the action and controller values and the incorrect url means these don't get rendered properly.

***Controller***

```
public class ExhibitController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CreateExhibitViewModel model = new CreateExhibitViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult New()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("New", model")   
        }

        // Process my model
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

***View***

```
@model RocketBook.Web.ViewModels.Exhibit.CreateExhibitViewModel

@{
    Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Put);
    ViewBag.Title = "Operation " + ViewBag.OperationName;
}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>New Exhibit</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-lg-6 form-horizontal">
            @using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form("create", "exhibit").Id("newexhibit").Type(FormType.Horizontal).FormMethod(FormMethod.Post).WidthLg(4)))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()                  
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Details</legend>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OperationID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.JobID)
                    @form.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.Barcode)
                    @form.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.ExhibitRef)
                    @form.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.ExhibitDescription)
                    @form.FormGroup().DropDownListFor(m => m.ClassificationGroupID, Model.ClassificationGroups).OptionLabel("")
                    @form.FormGroup().DropDownListFor(m => m.ClassificationID, Model.Classifications).OptionLabel("")
                    @form.FormGroup().DropDownListFor(m => m.ExhibitPriority, Model.EntityPriorities).OptionLabel("")
                </fieldset> 
                <hr />
                @(form.FormGroup().CustomControls(
                Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Style(ButtonStyle.Primary).Text("Add Exhibit")))

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I continued this discussion on the RestfulRouting Github page at

https://github.com/stevehodgkiss/restful-routing/issues/76

For anyone who also finds this behaviour and is confused, don't be, it is in fact the correct behaviour. Here is an explanaition from Steve Hodgkiss creator of the RestfulRouting project for ASP.NET MVC

> No that's expected, that's the path you go to when creating a model, and if something goes wrong it's only natural that it be halted there. When they pass validation they can move on...

A couple of solutions exist for distinguishing the URL. The HTTP Method used when calling

```
http://localhost/operations/1/exhibits
```

is a GET request and should call the Index action. If we have returned to this URL having had an error in the create action the HTTP method should be show as a POST. This can be accessed using

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod
```

Another solution as suggested by Khalid is:

> If you are using a ViewModel you could just flip a value on the ViewModel from inside the action. Since you are returning the model back in your Create action you can just touch a property. Might save you from having
>
> System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod
>   lingering in your code.
>
> Oh and if you put it on the viewmodel you can create a convention with a ActionFilter. If model == FlippyModel, just auto flip that property. If it fails, then that property will be true, if it passes you are moving on to the next view.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like the OperationsId is not being resolved into the url / form action.

What happens when you first come to the New page is that the **operationId** is being passed in by ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET MVC is being helpful by trying to find and using any **old** route values and plugging them into your route for you. Sounds confusing but let me explain by urls.

```
// url

/localhost/operations/1/exhibits/new

// on the view

Url.Action("create", "exhibits", new { /* operationId is implicit */ })
```

Next we do a POST to the create action.

```
// url 

/localhost/operations/1/exhibits

// on the view

Url.Action("create", "exhibits", new { /* operationId is missing! */ })
```

The issue arises when you get sent back to this page because the action from above is missing the **operationId**. This is a symptom of the route value dictionary in ASP.NET MVC (I have no idea why it does this, but it does).

Solution:

I make all my routes explicit, don't lean on ASP.NET MVC to give you the **implicit** values, because it is just too hard to remember when to use them. Instead just get in the habit of always being **explicit**.

```
// on new the view

Url.Action("create", "exhibits", new { operationId = Model.OperationId })

// on the edit view

Url.Action("update", "exhibits", new { operationId = Model.OperationId, id = Model.Id })
```

This will work every time and you don't have to worry about whether the value you need is sitting in the route value dictionary.

Comment: OK I wired up the Url.Action into a link which then posts back using Javascript. I still get exactly the same behaviour as my original question. Anymore thoughts?

Comment: ah I understand what you mean now, that is expected behavior for Restful Routing. You can't expect it to go to /new because the state was halted at the **post** action. Rails does the same exact thing.